# onActivityResult doesn't called

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I'm doing an activity which starts second activity. Then receives back a string from that activity. Although second activity starts and creates a new intent to send back string data. OnActivityResult doesn't called in first activity. I checked similar questions but they didn't help. Activity cycle stucks after second activity calls finish()

logcat prints this line:

```
"done with enterClicked().. going to onactivityresult"
```

but NOT this line :

```
"Entered onActivityResult()"
```

On first activity:

```
 static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

...
 Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(explicitIntent,GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On second activity:

```
String input=mEditText.getText().toString();

        Intent explicitly=new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
        explicitly.putExtra("mydata",input);


        setResult(RESULT_OK,explicitly);
        startActivity(explicitly);
        finish();
        Log.i(TAG,"done with enterClicked().. going to onactivityresult");
```

First activity's onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

        // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
     if(requestCode==GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Entered resultcode ok case()");

            Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
            String weneed = extras.getString("mydata");

            mUserTextView.setText(""+ weneed);


        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in this code:

```
String input=mEditText.getText().toString();

        Intent explicitly=new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
        explicitly.putExtra("mydata",input);


        setResult(RESULT_OK,explicitly);
        startActivity(explicitly);
        finish();
        Log.i(TAG,"done with enterClicked().. going to onactivityresult");
```

In your second activity you need to do this only --

```
Intent explicitly=new Intent();
```

Do not specif any argument and do not call `startActivity()` also just set the the result and finish your second activity.
What going wrong is you are starting your first activity again by your code. Not giving Android OS any chance to do its part. That's why your onActivityResult is not getting called.